# useReducer in customer hooks does not update the UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to use a useReducer to implement a custom hooks like useLegacyState mentioned in the official documentation to flexibly update the state in the component.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables

Only use useState or useReducer can be implemented:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/usereducer-update-any-05v82

However, I am unable to update the UI using custom hooks:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/customer-usestates-xxn01

Why?

Comment: Please put a [mcve] **in the question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your reducer function:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  return Object.assign({}, state, action);
}
```

The reason is
when you do `Object.assign(state, action)`, `state` also gets updated with attributes from `action`, which causes React not being able to disguise the original `state` from the updated `state`, hence [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) returns false since state and the updated state are the same.

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` doesn't seem to fit here. It's just that [React diffing algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) is unable to see the difference when the same object "reference" is used. Other than that, the code works great,  https://codesandbox.io/s/soanswer57235119-2dzrn